# heroku run python manage.py syncdb: timeout error

Tags: python, django, heroku, django-syncdb

when i'm running "heroku run python manage.py syncdb" in terminal i get error

```
Running `python manage.py syncdb` attached to terminal... up, run.4140
!    Heroku client internal error.
!    Search for help at: https://help.heroku.com
!    Or report a bug at: https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/new
Error:       Connection timed out - connect(2) (Errno::ETIMEDOUT)
Backtrace:   /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/client/rendezvous.rb:40:in `initialize'
             /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/client/rendezvous.rb:40:in `open'
             /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/client/rendezvous.rb:40:in `block in start'
             /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:68:in `timeout'
             /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/client/rendezvous.rb:31:in `start'
             /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/command/run.rb:132:in `rendezvous_session'
             /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/command/run.rb:119:in `run_attached'
             /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/command/run.rb:24:in `index'
             /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/command.rb:213:in `run'
             /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/cli.rb:28:in `start'
             /usr/local/heroku/bin/heroku:25:in `<main>'

Command:     heroku run python manage.py syncdb
Version:     heroku-toolbelt/3.1.1 (i686-linux) ruby/1.9.3
```

Comment: Are there any other errors before that?

Comment: no there aren't any errors

Comment: it seems a network error. Other commands run ok? (Ex: heroku run  python manage.py shell) ?

Comment: nope, heroku run commands are not working

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe it has nothing to do with this, but Someone had the same problem (with Rails) and posted a solution here:
http://www.orhancanceylan.com/heroku-run-command-operation-timed-out/

It says:

"While I was trying to run “heroku run rake db:migrate” command, I got “Operation timed out – connect(2) (Errno::ETIMEDOUT)” error. I spent hours to figure out what the reason is for that and realized that the internet provider in Italy, FASTWEB blocks the port number 5000. Therefore run command will not be able to executed. To handle this problem, what you need to do is simple: Just use “run:detached” i.e."

Try this:

> heroku run:detached python manage.py syncdb